# How to completely reset Spring Tool Suite 4 settings to default?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

My Spring Tool Suite 4 settings must have gotten screwed up, because whenever I import an existing Maven project, it does not link the project with my JRE. However, when I create a new Java project from scratch, it does link the project with my JRE.

I tried uninstalling Spring Tool Suite 4 and reinstalling (on Mac OS X) by simply dropping the application in the Trash and reinstalling the DMG. But are there any settings that are not being reset? Because I still get the same problem with the new Spring Tool Suite.

Where does Spring Tool Suite store its settings and how can I obliterate them so that it starts using default settings?

I want to delete any hidden files on my computer where it might be saving settings. I already tried deleting all the .metadata folders from my workspaces — didn't work.

Comment: on a mac it should be fine to delete the .app folder as well as the .metadata from the workspace.

Comment: have you tried `brew cask uninstall sts` ?